# Server-side COLLADA converter

Tags: python, 3d, webgl, collada, server-side-scripting

I'm building a web form to accommodate users uploading .obj and .fbx 3D models to a site. We need a server-side solution to convert these files to Collada (dae).

It would be massively helpful if someone could point me in the right direction as I have no solid ideas yet on a possible solution. I'd like to hear what others think before I go off down one path.

I can only think something along the lines of a python/perl script triggered off by the PHP during upload?

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a Python prograam on the server triggered by PHP. I would look around for a Python library for working with Collada files (e.g. http://collada.in4lines.com/) then I would use the [FBX Python SDK](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/pc/item?siteID=123112&id=10775847) to convert FBX files to Collada. For OBJ maybe something like http://pygame.org/wiki/OBJFileLoader would be helpful.

Update: I recently wrote a [blog post about using FBX and Python as a web server](https://area.autodesk.com/blogs/the-3ds-max-blog/serving_webgl_content_using_the_fbx_python_sdk/).

Comment: This sounds like really useful nformation. I'll look into it and report back. Thanks cdiggins!